# iOS: TCP socket without internet connection

Tags: ios, background, voip

I am writing an app that requires TCP connection to be active all the time in background even without internet connection and reboot. Is this possible in iOS 7+? I am having VOIP set as the background mode and it is awoken each time after 10 min regularly.

I need to write to VOIP output stream after every 5 or 8 mins.

Comment: Is it possible to have a TCP connection active in **ANY** system when it has no connection to wifi, a working network card, the phone network, etc.?  Usually when the server cannot be reached, the connection in TCP/IP is dropped...maybe you need a solution to reconnect regularly...

Comment: I need to save data if internet conenction is not available and write all data at once.

Comment: Then you will need to store it on the phone and upload it when the connection is available.  It's just like making a phone call...you can't talk into the phone if the call can't complete, but you can write down what you want to say and say it when you can make the call.

Comment: hmmm, I think I need a way to call a method in background after every 5 or 8 min only then.

Comment: Maybe...I am uncertain about the goal of your product.  If you are recording voice data to be sent when a connection is available, and actively communicating (real-time) when it is present, then that is about right.  Usually VOIP apps don't store data...unless you are talking about keeping voice messages for delivery when the connection is available...